# Standard notation for algorithm (instead of function)?

Tags: notation, computer-science

I am writing a math paper and defining various algorithms.

A function takes at least one input, and (may) output a result. The notation is

$$
\begin{align}
f :& \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}\\
&(x) \to x+1
\end{align}
$$

Say I wish to define an algorithm $A$ which outputs a value but takes no input. What is the notation for this? If I say $A=5$, then it is confusing because it just looks like $A$ is a variable.

I could implement it :

```
function A(){
   return 5;
}
```

and that would be clear.

But this notation provides a specific implementation of the algorithm. Say I was to talk about an algorithm (any algorithm) which outputs 5. How would I note this?

The closest I can think of is to use a unimplemented interface:

```
interface A() : 5
```

along with an explanatory note indicating that any implementation which satisfies this interface is accepted.

But, maybe there is a cleaner/standard notation?

Comment: I believe an algorithm is a type of function (defined on  appropriate sets).

Comment: @WilliamM. I thought so, but then I need an algorithm which takes no input; whereas a function needs to take at least one input. So they are not comparable.

Comment: You could have $A$ take input from a set with $1$ element, the empty tuple: $$A:\mathbb R^0\to\mathbb R$$ $$()\mapsto5$$

Comment: It seems clearest to just use the phrase "always outputs 5" in complete sentences where needed. If you really find that too wordy, you could let some symbol $C$ denote the set of algorithms with this property and then use "$\in C$".

Answer (score 1):

I would say that the answer depends on the specific case, and the first answer I can think of is that your algorithm probably does have input parameters, even if they might be trivial for your case.

What I mean is, you might want to denote your algorithm as a function mapping input states to output states, usually encoding the input parameters in the input state (which is the standard way in CS, I would say). Since in your case you have no parameters, the initial state would be trivial since it does not contain any binding corresponding to input parameters.

If that's the case, then maybe something like a denotational semantic approach would work, e.g. $[\![ \cdot]\!] : Program \,\times \, State \to  State$ so that the function you are interested in would be $[\![ \textbf{return }5]\!]$.

Then (intuitively, since you would need to define the whole grammar/semantic of your language) you would get that, consider the input state $\sigma = \varnothing$ where a state is defined as a set of (variable, value) pairs, the result might look like $[\![ \textbf{return }5]\!]\sigma = \sigma'$ for $\sigma' = \{(retval, 5)\}$, assuming the semantic of the return statement binds it to some special identifyer "retval".

**On the other hand**, this might be too complex/unnecessary/introduce too much noise in the paper and you might get away with simply defining the algorithm in text form such as "We denote with $A$ the algorithm taking no input arguments and returning an integer value s.t. $A() = 5$"

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment. I would perhaps focus less on the algorithm and more on the algorithmic problem you are trying to solve. For instance, subroutines of the form "we can compute x within desired resource bounds" are often deferred to lemmas when writing up results. As someone who works in TCS + Pure Math, I am skeptical that your problem does not have any sort of instance/input. That instance/input would be either (i) the input for the algorithm, or (ii) the processed input from previous steps.

If these are your novel results that you are writing up for arXiv/publication, I would strongly recommend talking with your advisor or a trusted mentor about formatting, conventions, etc. It would also be worth looking at the literature for similar works to see how folks in your subfield write. I am happy to try and offer more advice if you want to share more details. However, if you are writing up your novel results, it would really be better to talk with someone you trust and to keep things confidential until you post to arXiv.